# Update UISplitView's DetailView from Second Level Navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, ipad

I have an iPad app with a `UISplitView`. In the Root View I have a two level `UITableView` Navigation(it takes its content from a plist). In the Detail View I have a `UIWebView` that I am trying to update. I can update the Detailview from the 1st level navigation, but when I push the second level nav and try to update the detailview, it does not work.

Basically, the second level Nav doesn't have access to self.DetailViewController(like the 1st level does). How do I get access to the DetailViewController from the "pushed" second level so I can update its UIWebView?

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `detailViewController` as a property for your `SecondLevelViewController` and before you push the controller you just set the property.

```
SecondLevelViewController *secondController = ...
secondController.detailViewController = self.detailViewController;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES];
```

And in `SecondLevelViewController` you define the property for `DetailViewController` just as it is defined in `RootViewController`.